# Strange behavior with recursion and Kernel#rand (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, recursion, random

I have a method like this in Ruby:

```
def guess
  random_guess = rand(4)
  if random_guess == 0
    guess
  end

  puts random_guess
end
guess
```

As you can see, it is meant to generate a random number between 0 and 4 and then recur if the number is 0. The idea is to keep the method from ever printing out 0. However, it does not seem to be behaving this way for some strange reason. E.g., here is an example in IRB when `random_guess` gets a value of 0:

```
2.2.0 :001 > def guess
2.2.0 :002?>     random_guess = rand(4)
2.2.0 :003?>     if random_guess == 0
2.2.0 :004?>         guess
2.2.0 :005?>       end
2.2.0 :006?>     
2.2.0 :007 >       puts random_guess
2.2.0 :008?>   end
 => :guess 
2.2.0 :009 > guess
2
0
0
0
0
 => nil 
2.2.0 :010 >
```

When it does not get a value of 0, the program behaves normally and simply prints out any other random number in that range:

```
2.2.0 :010 > guess
1
 => nil 
2.2.0 :011 >
```

What I'm wondering is why the program behaves so strangely upon the recursion that happens when `random_guess` is 0. It looks like it is recurring, but it does not appear to be stopping at the right condition, i.e., when `random_guess` is not 0. Why is this happening?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `else`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `random_guess` is `0`, `guess` calls itself recursively, this is working correctly. The output you see is because `puts random_guess` is executed *after* the recursion. So when you see the output as, e.g:

```
3
0
```

1. `guess` is called as this: `random_guess` gets `0`, so call `guess`.
2. Inside the *inner* `guess`, `random_guess` gets `3`, puts the
   current `random_guess`, which is `3`. exits the *inner* `guess`
3. puts the value of `random_guess` in the *outter* `guess`, which is
   `0`, then exits.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what you told it to.  If you get a non-zero, you don't enter the `if`-clause, so you immediately print the non-zero and are done.

However, if the first value you generate is zero, you enter the recursion and repeat the process until a non-zero value is produced.  Only then do you bypass the `if` to encounter the print statement and return from the recursion.  Since the recursion was only invoked if you had a zero, you now print that zero and return.

Net result, the output will be a non-zero value, followed by all the zeros that occurred, in reverse order as you pop off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Because it `recursive`. in maintain a stack of each remaining instruction.

Say if 0 comes, it will add `puts random_guess` line in stack. and after finishing of recursive `guess` call, it pop out the remaining instructions.

So it printing 0 till many recursive call of `guess`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# closer to your original design
# fyi, returns values 1 - 3
def guess
  random_guess = 0
  while random_guess == 0
    random_guess = get_random_guess(4)
  end

  random_guess
end

def get_random_guess(max_guess)
    rand(4)
end

# test guess 100 times
(1..100).each { puts "guess=#{guess}" }



# faster, note the use of rand without a max parameter. 
# in this case, rand returns a float between 0 and 1
# this return values between min_guess and max_guess
def faster_guess(min_guess, max_guess)
  (rand() * (max_guess + 1 - min_guess)).to_i + min_guess
end

# test faster_guess 100 times
# will return values between 1 - 4
(1..100).each { puts "faster_guess=#{faster_guess(1,4)}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you put your `puts` statement inside your method, it will print out the value of the random guess on every invocation, whether it was `0` or not. A method calling itself recursively will only break control flow at that point temporarily, until it moves back up the stack.

What you want to do is have the method return the first value that is not `0`. Example:

```
def guess
  random_guess = rand(4)
  (random_guess > 0) ? random_guess : guess
end

puts guess
# 1 (never 0)
```

In this modified method, the conditional will return the `random_guess` if it is larger than `0`. If not, it will recursively call itself until the condition is met.

Note that this usage of recursion **theoretically** creates the possibility of infinite recursion and, although this will never happen in practice, the execution time of the method will be random.

Comment: The execution time will be random, but it terminates rapidly in expectation.  On average it will do 4/3 recursive calls, and the odds of requiring more than 20 calls are less than one in a trillion.

Comment: Hence the double emphasis on *theoretically* and *this will never happen in practice*. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but I see this observation too frequently on stackoverflow, and this was the second time today. In response to another question somebody was hassling a student who was using the prof's code, saying that the prof should be barred from teaching because acceptance/rejection techniques are O(infinity) so only an idiot would use them.  Acceptance/rejection is often not the best choice (as in this question), but sometimes it's the only choice and it's a valid technique.

Comment: Yes. I definitely not support it in a dichotomous sense that would outlaw its use. I have used accept/reject myself in some implementations. I added a highlight to my answer to further emphasize the theoretical nature of this aside.